How do I ensure that all images are indexed by Google when using the carousel pattern?
This is how the main product picture appears on my website:

and it has the following markup:
<div>
  <img
    alt="Force Factor, ProbioSlim"
    class="dialog__trigger cursor_pointer"
    decoding="async"
    fetchpriority="high"
    height="1610"
    sizes="100vw"
    src="/supplements/probioslim-1865/images/triptych.avif?width=480"
    style="aspect-ratio:2716 / 1610"
    title="Force Factor, ProbioSlim supplement label"
    width="2716"
    data-scope="dialog"
    data-part="trigger"
    id="dialog::R5r335::trigger"
    aria-haspopup="dialog"
    type="button"
    aria-expanded="false"
    data-state="closed">
</div>

If user clicks on the image, then a dialog appears that shows upsized version of the image.
I want to add a second picture for the same product: What markup should I use?
Related, my image includes width= parameter, but I want Google to index the version without width attribute, i.e. /supplements/probioslim-1865/images/triptych.avif. How do I indicate that in the markup?

Do you use JavaScript to popup the upsized version of the images? If so, it's better to add these images to an image sitemap:

Image sitemaps are a way of telling Google about other images on your site, especially those that we might not otherwise find (such as images your site reaches with JavaScript code).

For example:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
    xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
  <url>
    <loc>https://example.com/sample1.html</loc>
    <image:image>
      <image:loc>https://example.com/image1.jpg</image:loc>
    </image:image>
    <image:image>
      <image:loc>https://example.com/image2.jpg</image:loc>
    </image:image>
  </url>
</urlset>


A well formulated answer!

Regarding your second point -
Assuming the ?width=480 is resizing the image server-side, I'd perhaps think about using the srcset attribute to serve the large image to users on higher resolution screens, and also have that as the fallback.  For all other users, serve the small image.
Something like this, though you may want something more complex, especially if the large image is more than twice the size of the small one.
srcset="/supplements/probioslim-1865/images/triptych.avif?width=480 1x, /supplements/probioslim-1865/images/triptych.avif 2x"
   src="/supplements/probioslim-1865/images/triptych.avif"

I can't guarantee this will definitely work, but the markup should mean that Google at least know the location of the best quality image (minus ?width), and also users on high resolution monitors get a better looking site.  The markup would be signalling what is going on.

Decent article on srcset - https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/05/responsive-images-done-right-guide-picture-srcset/
